# Progmatically change UIBarButtonItem identifier on UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

So I am just using a normal View Controller. I dragged a Navigation bar to the top and added a UIBarButtonItem with the 'pause' identifier.

I want to be able to change that identifier to the 'play' one.

Is this possible? I can't find any information on it.

I tried creating a new one, but not really sure where to go from there.

```
    UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Flip"
                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                              target:self
                              action:@selector(flipView)];
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay`. Just set it up, assign your selector and target, and choose which barButtonItem you want.

```
 UIBarButtonItem *playButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self action:@selector(playButtonPressed:)];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = playButton;//Or leftBarButtonItem if you want it to be on the left
```

Comment: thanks! So since I just dragged the navigationbar onto a viewController when I try to do that it's not adding anything to it. Is there a way to do like self.navBar.rightBarButtonItem?

Comment: You could just create a reference outlet to the actual UIBarButtonItem that you're placing on the NavigationBar and assign directly to it. It's easier to just use a navigationController though (especially since you have to account for the status bar in iOS 7)